# why is socketIo creating multiple connections incrementally?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

server-side:

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

const users = [];

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("A user connected", socket.id);

  // Emit the list of connected clients when a user connects or reconnects
  if(users.length){
    console.log(users);
  emitConnectedClients();
  }

  // Receive the setUsername event from the client
  socket.on("setUsername", (username) => {
    // Associate the username with the socket connection
    socket.username = username.FirstName;
    console.log(
      `Username ${socket.username} is associated with socket ${socket.id}`
    );

    const existingUser = users.find((user) => user.username === socket.username);
    if (existingUser) {
      // Update the user's socket ID if it has changed (reconnection)
      if (existingUser.socketId !== socket.id) {
        existingUser.socketId = socket.id;
        console.log("existing user:", users);
      }
    } else {
      // Add a new user to the users array
      users.push({ socketId: socket.id, username: socket.username });
      console.log("New User:", users);
    }

    // Emit the updated list of connected clients to all clients
    emitConnectedClients();

    // Emit the "userConnected" event to all clients except the newly connected user
    socket.broadcast.emit("userConnected", socket.username);
  });

  // Handle custom events from the client
  socket.on("privateMessage", (data) => {
    console.log(data.senderId);
    // Find the recipient user from the users array
    const recipientUser = users.find((user) => user.socketId === data.recipientId);
    if (recipientUser) {
      // Emit the private message only to the recipient
      socket.to(data.recipientId).emit("privateMessage", data.message);
    }
  });

  // Handle disconnection
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} disconnected`);

    // Remove the disconnected user from the users array
    const index = users.findIndex((user) => user.socketId === socket.id);
    if (index !== -1) {
      const disconnectedUser = users.splice(index, 1)[0];
      // Emit the updated list of connected clients to all clients
      emitConnectedClients();
      // Emit the "userDisconnected" event to all clients
      io.emit("userDisconnected", disconnectedUser.username);
    }
  });

  function emitConnectedClients() {
    io.emit(
      "connectedClients",
      users.map((user) => [user.socketId, user.username, "sent from server"])
    );
  }
});
```

client-side:

```
const newSocket = io("http://localhost:3000", { autoConnect: false });
const ChatRoom = () => {
  const signedInUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.user.isLoggedIn);

  const [selectedChat, setSelectedChat] = useState([]);
  const listItemClickHandler = (elem) => {
    setSelectedChat(elem);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      newSocket.connect();
      newSocket.emit("setUsername", signedInUser);
    }
    return () => {
      newSocket.disconnect()
    };
  }, []);
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
  const [activeUsers, setActiveUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("user list effect ran", userList);
    setActiveUsers(() =>
      userList.filter((elem) => {
        return elem[0] !== newSocket.id;
      })
    );
  }, [userList]);

  newSocket.on("privateMessage", (eventData) => {
    console.log("a new message recieve");
    console.log("Message data: " + eventData);
  });

  newSocket.on("connectedClients", (users) => {
    
    if (users) {console.log("connected clients ran");
      setUserList(users);
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="chatroom-container">
      <div className="chatroom-header">
        <h1>Chat Room</h1>
      </div>
      <span>
        <ChatList
          listItemClick={(elem) => listItemClickHandler(elem)}
          activeUsers={activeUsers}
        />
        <div className="chat-area-conntainer">
          <ChatComponent selectedChat={selectedChat} socket={newSocket} />
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};
const disconnectSocket = () => {
  if (newSocket) {
    newSocket.disconnect();
  }
};
```

I am trying to create a chat app using socketio and node, react

The socketio `.on()` methods are running multiple times incrementally i.e. every iteration of an action like re-login or new user connected the connected event runs 'previous+2 times'. I can't wrap my head around this. I have been looking around the docs from socketio, still no result

I was expecting it to run only once.... Please help!

Comment: Please give more details about “'previous+2 times'”, like a list of the events you see. It looks like every time an user connect, it sends a message to every user already connected, isn't it expected that it sends more messages over time?

Comment: there are basically two events one is set user and private message and when i join the socket network as a new user , console.log("connected clients ran") runs initially two times, if another user joins then it runs 4 times.. then if another , then 6 times and so on, mean while if i send a private message , then it would 8 times, if another  then 10 times.. i'm so confused by this, i cant figure out if the client is causing this or the server side....